# Can two .pbix files be merged into one?

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder3.0

Is it possible to merge two .pbix files into one so that one dashboard can be built?  If both .pbix files use the same data source and one developer works on a page and another developer works on a second page, can the two .pbix files successfully be merged so that there is one .pbix file with two pages?  I'm thinking if the two files are in Github repository, can Github merge the two files into one?

Comment: As per my knowledge, it's a manual work and you have to copy things from one to another. But as you also mentioned about the dashboard, after publishing both reports you can create a dashboard. And in the dashboard, you can select visuals from different reports.